# How to Patch Update Android studio from 0.8.1 to 0.9.9?

Tags: android, updates

I cannot see the update option when I check for update in Android studio. However, the update message says, it's a patch but redirects to download the whole android studio when I click on download. I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

[image: android_studio_update]

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot update from 0.8.1 to 0.9.9 (or higher), except by replacing the entire installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio 0.8.12 introduced [some changes to the patching mechanism](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio0812released). Because of this, it is not possible to patch from pre-0.8.12 to post-0.8.12 at all. You need to download and install a full copy. Your settings should be preserved by default, however.